# OpenGl ES 2.0 putting a texture on a single face

Tags: android, textures, opengl-es-2.0

I have a cube which I can render as a single colour or as a textured cube.

How would I texture just a single face and leave the rest of the cube a single colour

I have played about with the shader, I have also only included texture corrds for the first face.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic answer is that you would have to create two separate meshes, one with a shader that renders a solid color, and one with a shader that renders a texture. And then draw each of them in separate draw calls.

If you want to save yourself from an extra draw call and shader, you could create a texture atlas, where there is a small white area on the texture that you map to the solid color faces with appropriate texture coordinates, and then map the area with the image you want to the textured face.

Comment: I am giving this a go, making a cube and a billboard next to each other.  having some issues with transparency (the billboard is trans, but clears down the cube.)

Comment: You probably want blendmode GL_ONE, GL_ZERO if you don't want the faces transparent. And make sure depth testing and depth writing are on.